# how to show 1 row that have many columns in mysql query

Tags: html, mysql

I have this table in my mysql database

```
+------------+---------+
|    Age     |  Name   |
+------------+---------+
| 30         | A       |
+------------+---------+
| 24         | B       |
+------------+---------+
| 30         | C       |
+------------+---------+
| 24         | D       |
+------------+---------+
```

and I want to display the new table like this

```
+------------+---------+
|    Age     |  Name   |
+------------+---------+
| 30         | A       |
+            +---------+
|            | C       |
+------------+---------+
| 24         | B       |
+            +---------+
|            | D       |
+------------+---------+
```

Anyone have a idea how to solve this.Thanks for any help in advance.Here's the code,it keep showing the duplicate age.And sorry if this was not clear enough.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dupe.age),name
FROM customer
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT age
            FROM customer
            GROUP BY age
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        ) dupe
            ON dupe.age = customer.age
```

Comment: Select as-is, then group in your code right before output

Comment: cant work .Its only show a single name only.thanks for help

Comment: so? what is your question then?

Comment: [Here's a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7b50/1) with the parts I have.  If you create one with your `bb_customer` table as well as `customer` that may help us help you.

Comment: I have a data in my database like the first table and I want to show it in html like the second table.Is it possible to use mysql query only or any idea that i can show it exactly like my second table given?

Comment: sorry ,have a wrong in my code .I already update my question.Actually I just use one database that named customer.Not the bb_customer.truly sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `GROUP_CONCAT` instead:

```
SELECT
  age,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name)
FROM
  customer
GROUP BY age
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

***[The SQLFIDDLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7b50/12)***

Comment: Thank you @xdazz .This is mostly what I looking for.But still look perfect and great idea.I will use this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(dupe.age),name
FROM customer
    INNER JOIN
    (   SELECT age
        FROM customer
        GROUP BY age
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) dupe
        ON dupe.age = customer.age
ORDER BY age DESC, name
```

If you want to display the distinct age only once (as per your diagram), see the answer from @xdazz.  Specifically, do you want 4 rows, 2 with the age null for the second, or do you want 2 rows, each with two names.  If the latter, see the answer from @xdazz.